# How to check if a list already contains an element in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have been working on this for quite a time and my if statement does not seem to have any effect on the code. what I am trying to do is that I want to enter words in a list without repetition.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    if lst.count(words) == 0:
        lst = lst + words
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: to get the unique items in a list, you could do this: `non_repeat_list = list(set(repeat_list))`

Comment: @Andy - That's not a duplicate. This question's membership check is failing because it is checking whether a list exists within another list. If it does not, it extends the list. E.g., `[1, 2, 3] in [2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3]` is being expected to return `True`, but that's not its actual behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), it ensures unique elements. Alternatively, you can use the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) operator to check for membership in a list (*albeit an order of magnitude less efficient*).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> instuff = """one two three
... two three four
... three four five
... """
>>> lst = set()
>>> for line in instuff.split("\n"):
...   lst |= set(line.split())
... 
>>> lst
set(['four', 'five', 'two', 'three', 'one'])
>>>
```

Comment: `set.union(*(set(line.split()) for line in instuff.splitlines()))`